# Using QLPreviewPanel with Electron

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, quicklook

We are looking into migrating our Objc Application to an Electron one, since the native one is just a WebWrapper around a website already.

We are missing one important feature: the ability to use QuickLook to preview files.

We managed to wrap `qlmanage` (Quick Look Server debug and management tool) in a npm module (based on this [older code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quicklook)) but this is not the same as using QLPreviewPanel.

`qlmanage` launches an app in the Dock, and can spawn multiple instances of it, unlike QLpreviewPanel.

[image]

- Does anyone managed to use Quicklook properly with Electron?
- Is it possible to create a npm module in C++ using the Foundation Framework from Apple, and then requiring this module from Electron?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We ended up adding this feature directly in Electron.

This will be released soon on the `BrowserWindow` api, with the following method signature:

`previewFile(path [,displayname])`

This way everyone gets to use it!